# Ubuntu 23.10 does not power off, but 22.04 on the same system powers off properly

Tags: shutdown, 23.10

I have a PC with two hard drives with Ubuntu Desktop:

1. The first hard disk originally had version 18.04 and I just put 22.04.3 LTS over that, everything fine. Mounts windows partitions and all.

   [image: 22.04.3 HW/SW]
2. On the new hard disk I did a new installation with 23.10. However, this one does not power off. Only HDD gets powered off. Monitor, PC fans, LEDs stay on. I tried changing the NVIDIA drivers to 535, but it did not work. If I suspend the system, it dies.

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2023-10-26 10:37:42

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Hewlett-Packard p7-1254
- **Memory:**                                      8.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   AMD A6-3620 APU with Radeon™ HD Graphics × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD SUMO
- **Disk Capacity:**                               2.6 TB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            7.06
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.0
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-9-generic

So Ubuntu 23.10 on the same PC is not working. Is there a way to fix that? Perhaps I need to copy something from the 22.04 partition that will make the 23.10 partition work?

Comment: Do you have logs from just before the shutdown?  Start a shutdown, wait for it to hang, use SysRq keys to reboot and check the previous boot's final log entries.

Comment: the log is very long  just some  added

Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd[1]: Reached target poweroff.target - System Power Off.
Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd-journald[295]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
Oct 28 10:51:57 jorge-p7-1254 systemd-journald[295]: Journal stopped